# c# - httpClient.PostAsync returns null in PHP echo server. How solve it?

Tags: c#, php, json, server, client

httpClient.PostAsync returns null in PHP echo server. I read many posts about this problem and none of them solved my problem.
Some of my C# side codes(.net 4.8 vs 2022):

```
     public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }

    }

    public static string url1 = "https://test.test/controller/app/test.php";
    

    static async Task<string> SendURI(Uri u, HttpContent c)
    {
        HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };

        var response = string.Empty;
        using (var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler))
        {
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                RequestUri = u,
                Content = c
            };

            HttpResponseMessage result = await client.SendAsync(request);
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //response = result.StatusCode.ToString();
                response = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString();
            }
        }
        return response;
    }

    private async void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var person = new Person
        {
            Name = "John",
            Age = "34"
        };
        var data = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(person);
        var dataS = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        string res = await SendURI(new Uri(url1),dataS);
        MessageBox.Show(res);
    }
```

and php side(test.php php ver 8.1):

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
var_dump($data);
```

response always is null what's the problem?

Comment: Maybe decoding failed. Test with just `$data = file_get_contents('php://input'); var_dump($data);` and see if you get any other result.

Comment: $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
//var_dump($json);

print_r($json); result == string(0) ""

Comment: echo file_get_contents("php://input"); result ==string(0) too

Comment: Have you tested the url in Postman or any other alike tool to see if the php endpoint is actually returning data? So that you can basically see if it's a problem on the C# or PHP side

Comment: I use XAMPP server in localhost and my SSL is self-signed and HttpClient.GetAsync Method worked really good but HttpClient.postAsync Method return null.

Comment: Use postman to test the endpoint, as suggested. Make a POST request with the same JSON in the body and set the same headers as your C# code, and see if you get a correct response. This will help you to see if something is wrong in the C#. You can also use a tool like Fiddler or Wireshark to inspect the HTTP requests and see what's in them and whether the structure is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all friends who helped. Postman results are quite similar. My problem was quite specific. I removed .htaccess file. RewriteEngine with RewriteRules redirect my urls.